# Nokogiri Gem wont parse the file using SAX handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri, sax

I have xml file with header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

and also it contains the

```
<transmission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

when used the SAX parser it wont parse. But when manually removed the encoding part and the attributes after transmission;XML parsing success. Being the file is large;I can use only SAX.Is there any other way to parse this xml file without manually removing the encoding and transmission attributes.

Sample Code is

```
      require 'nokogiri'
        include Nokogiri



class P < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document

      def initialize
      end

      def start_element(element, attributes = [])
        puts element
      end

      def cdata_block(string)
      end

      def characters(string)
      end

      def end_element(element)
        puts element
      end
 end

    parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(P.new())
    parser.parse_file('file_dummy.xml')
```

Comment: It it important to use the SAX parser? Maybe it's a bug in that library.

Comment: @tadman It is a large file , only option is use the SAX parser only.

Comment: It might be worth providing a bit of code that explains how you're engaging this with Nokogiri. Right now it seems like a bug in SAX, but it could be an issue with how Nokogiri interfaces with it.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We can't duplicate the problem without the minimum code that demonstrates it. If you think it's a bug in Nokogiri, you should file a bug report with the developers. Either way you'll have to show why it doesn't do what you think it should.

Comment: Your sample code is not syntactically correct. You're missing a trailing `end` to close the class.

Comment: @theTinMan: sorry for the issue , i will update in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous referrals. I got the answer. It is the answer from @thetinman.But not fully absorbed. Used a sed command to replace utf-16 with utf-8 and parse the file. Why i need the sed operation is nokogiri causes issue with this utf-16

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the suite of SAX methods and see what you get:

```
require 'nokogiri'

class MyDoc < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  def cdata_block(str)
    puts "cdata_block: #{str}"
  end

  def characters(str)
    puts "characters: #{str}"
  end

  def comment(str)
    puts "comment: #{str}"
  end

  def end_element(str)
    puts "end_element: #{str}"
  end

  def end_document
    puts "end_document"
  end

  def end_element_namespace(name, prefix = nil, uri = nil)
    puts "end_element_namespace: name: #{name} prefix: #{prefix} uri: #{uri}"
  end

  def error(str)
    puts "error:#{str}"
  end

  def processing_instruction(name, content)
    puts "processing_instruction: name: #{name} content: #{content}"
  end

  def start_document
    puts "start_document"
  end

  def start_element(str, attrs = [])
    puts "start_element: #{str} attrs: #{attrs}"
  end

  def start_element_namespace(name, attrs=[], prefix=nil, uri=nil, ns=[])
    puts "start_element_namespace: name: #{name} attrs: #{attrs} prefix: #{prefix} uri: #{uri} ns: #{ns}"
  end

  def warning(str)
    puts "warning: #{str}"
  end

  def xmldecl(version, encoding, standalone)
    puts "xmldecl: version: #{version} encoding: #{encoding} standalone: #{standalone}"
  end
end

parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(MyDoc.new)
parser.parse(File.open(ARGV[0]))
```

Save that to a script and run it using:

```
ruby path/to/script.rb path/to/file.xml
```

You should see output. For instance, using the following as a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I get the following output:

```
xmldecl: version: 1.0 encoding:  standalone:
start_document
start_element_namespace: name: catalog attrs: [] prefix:  uri:  ns: []
characters:

start_element_namespace: name: book attrs: [#<struct Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser::Attribute localname="id", prefix=nil, uri=nil, value="bk101">] prefix:  uri:  ns: []
characters:

start_element_namespace: name: author attrs: [] prefix:  uri:  ns: []
characters: Gambardella, Matthew
end_element_namespace: name: author prefix:  uri:
characters:

start_element_namespace: name: title attrs: [] prefix:  uri:  ns: []
characters: XML Developer's Guide
end_element_namespace: name: title prefix:  uri:
characters:

start_element_namespace: name: genre attrs: [] prefix:  uri:  ns: []
characters: Computer
end_element_namespace: name: genre prefix:  uri:
characters:

start_element_namespace: name: price attrs: [] prefix:  uri:  ns: []
characters: 44.95
end_element_namespace: name: price prefix:  uri:
characters:

start_element_namespace: name: publish_date attrs: [] prefix:  uri:  ns: []
characters: 2000-10-01
end_element_namespace: name: publish_date prefix:  uri:
characters:

start_element_namespace: name: description attrs: [] prefix:  uri:  ns: []
characters: An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.
end_element_namespace: name: description prefix:  uri:
characters:

end_element_namespace: name: book prefix:  uri:
characters:
end_element_namespace: name: catalog prefix:  uri:
end_document
```

Comment: error:Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content